# Google Cloud - Downloading data from bucket to instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying download the whole data from my bucket (tracking-data) on google cloud to my instance (instance-1) on Linux system.

I see some options here:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#transfergcloud 
but I'm not sure there's a way there to download from bucket to instance.

I'm accessing my instance through my terminal and I've made a few tries with gsutil, but not successfully so far.
Any idea how can I download the whole bucket into my instance? (preferably to put it in MDNet/data, I don't have such directory yet, but I probably should store the data there).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, check the API access rights for your Compute Engine service account:

[image]

For instance, read only:

[image]

Then, just use `gsutil cp` ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)) or even `gsutil rsync` ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync)):

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://<your-bucket>/* <destination_folder>
```

---

*Disclaimer: Comments and opinions are my own and not the views of my employer.*

Comment: Allow default access is checked, isn't that ok?
I've already tried gsutil cp gs://tacking-data/* , I get:
CommandException: Wrong number of arguments for "cp" command.

Comment: You missed the destination folder. Try: `gsutil -m cp -r gs://tacking-data/* .` (where `.` is your current folder).

Comment: Same error.
CommandException: Wrong number of arguments for "cp" command.

Comment: I'm doing the exact same thing like the print screen you sent. Any idea why I get that error?

Comment: You should probably check your local configuration. `gsutil -m cp -r gs://tracking-data/* <destination_dir>` is syntactically correct.

Comment: When I used gsutil -m cp -r gs://tracking-data/* from my home folder I got an error. Only after I created MDNet/data, got back to home directory and typed:
gsutil -m cp -r gs://tracking-data/* MDNet/data it worked! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `gsutil cp` or `gsutil rsync`

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync

Comment: I've already tried gsutil cp gs://tracking-data
I get CommandException: Wrong number of arguments for "cp" command.

Comment: I need to download the data into MDNet/data (I don't have that folder on my instance, so I also  need to create that folder in my instance).

Comment: @Niminim `mkdir -p MDNet/data && gsutil rsync gs://tracking-data MDNet/data`

Comment: I see:
Building synchronization state...
Starting synchronization...

And that's it. Seems like nothing else happens.

Comment: When I used gsutil -m cp -r gs://tracking-data/* from my home folder I got an error. Only after I created MDNet/data, got back to home directory and typed:
gsutil -m cp -r gs://tracking-data/* MDNet/data it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In zsh you will most likely get this issue

```
gsutil -m cp -r 'gs://arxiv-dataset/arxiv/arxiv/pdf/23*/' /data/
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding fullstop after hitting a space at the end helped me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).